# passing argument/arguments signal to callback on GTK+ in C

Tags: c++, c, gtk, signals

Here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

G_MODULE_EXPORT void waka(GtkWidget *button, GtkWidget* entry1)
{
printf("%s",gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry1)));
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

GtkWidget *window, *button, *entry;

gtk_init(&argc,&argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

button = gtk_button_new_with_label("hha");
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button),"clicked",G_CALLBACK(waka),entry);

entry = gtk_entry_new();

GtkWidget *vbox;

vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE,2);

gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(vbox),button);
gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(vbox),entry);

gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox);


gtk_widget_show_all(window);
gtk_main();


return 0;
}
```

When I launch it, and try to fill in some string in the entry box, and then click the button, it said 'segmentation fault'. What is going on?

Also, the callback only works with one user data argument. How about if I want two or more arguments, what must I do in the callback function, and in the call to `g_signal_connect()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem is that you're trying to use pointer to *entry* **before** initializing it. I've changed a bit your code to fix this, see if it will work for you:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

void waka(GtkWidget *button, GtkWidget* entry1)
{
 g_print("entry: %s\n", gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry1)));
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
 GtkWidget *window, *button, *entry, *vbox;

 gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

 window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
 button = gtk_button_new_with_label("hha");
 entry = gtk_entry_new();
 vbox = gtk_vbox_new(FALSE, 2);

 gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(vbox),button);
 gtk_box_pack_start_defaults(GTK_BOX(vbox),entry);

 gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window),vbox);

 g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(waka), entry);

 gtk_widget_show_all(window);
 gtk_main();

 return 0;
}
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: thx dude, anyway how to passing two more widget to callback, do i need usingg struct? or i need to declare the widget globally (ex. static var/out of function var) ??

Comment: you can use callback's second parameter to pass any data you need, including pointer to array of widgets or list of widgets or custom structure.